# Modern news headlines show file names

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, modern-experience, sharepoint-news

I use the news web-part in several sites in our SP, but I get the file names as headlines, instead of the actual headline. I have searched through google several times, but I'm unable to find a solution.

Do any of you have ideas on how to solve this? Does it have some thing to do with the danish language setting?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure this is news webpart? Which layout you have used for your webpart? Can you please try removing and re-adding it on your page by following [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-the-news-web-part-on-a-sharepoint-page-c2dcee50-f5d7-434b-8cb9-a7feefd9f165) article??

Answer (score 0):

I did a test in SharePoint online, but I couldn't reproduce your issue.

[image]

Does it also display the file name instead of the headline name in the actual page?

If you still have this issue after recreating the web part, I recommend your [create service requests to contact Office 365 support.](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/praveenkumar/2013/07/17/how-to-create-service-requests-to-contact-office-365-support/)